# C sscanf not working with float

Tags: c, scanf

In the following code

```
scanf("%s", input);
sscanf(input," %s %f ", change, &grades);
printf("%s\n", change);
printf("%f", grades);
```

grades will be printed as `0.00`, no matter the input. Why doesn't `sscanf` recognise float format?

Comment: How is `grades` defined?

Comment: and what have you input into `input`?

Comment: as a float type

Comment: Please include the full code, along with the input (actually what you typed into the keyboard for the scanf), and the exact output.

Comment: the program must recognise if the input is in farenheit degrees or celsius and convert the grades into the other scale.

Comment: Check the return type of scanf and sscanf - they should return 1 and 2 respectively. (They return the number of successful format items read)

Comment: The code is much larger, this is the part that i'm sure it breaks. 

`code` 
  char input[100], change[10];
  float grades;
  scanf("%s", input);
  sscanf(input," %s %f ", change, &grades);
  printf("%s\n", change);
  printf("%f", grades);
`code`

input: -f 50.00
output: -f 0.00

Comment: `scanf("%s", input);` will read only one string, if you type `"celsius 34.7"`, only `"celsius"` will be passed to `sscanf`.

Comment: Yeap, solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first call to `scanf` is looking for a sequence of characters delimited by whitespace.  If your input looks something like this:

```
test 98.3
```

Then `input` will only contain the string `test`.

If you want to read a full line of text so you can later parse it with `sscanf`, use `fgets` instead which will read a line:

```
char input[100];
char change[10];
float grades;

fgets(input, 100, stdin);
sscanf(input," %s %f ", change, &grades);
printf("%s\n", change);
printf("%f", grades);
```

Input:

```
test 96.5
```

Output:

```
test
96.500000
```

Comment: Yeap, that was it!

Comment: Thank you!
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", str)` reads from `stdin` upto a newline or whitespace that mean you are reading input as `change78.12` here `change` is change string value and `78.12` is float grade value. when you'll do `sscanf(str, "%s %f", change, &grade)` since `str` is valid `%s` type so it will read by change only so nothing left for grade so it takes default as `0.00` . If you want to read from `stdin` and then do `scanf` then do this.

```
// input format is (separated by whitespace)
// change 78.5
fgets(input, input_length, stdin);

sscanf(input,"%s %f ", change, &grades);
printf("%s\n", change);
printf("%f", grades);
```